# Can't get sub_filter to work in nginx, could it be an ownership/permissions issue?

Tags: nginx, scripting

I have http_sub_module installed, but the 'sub_filter' line is not working. I'm trying to use it for a dynamic nonce for CSP as per [these instructions](https://scotthelme.co.uk/csp-nonce-support-in-nginx/), replacing some text in script tags with the variable set in a conf file. The nonce is showing up in the CSP header, but not in the script tag, it just shows the text that needs to be replaced. I have gzip on and added the proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""; line. Could this be a permissions/ownership issue regarding the PHP files and/or website directories?

The server block has this configuration in it:

```
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
set_secure_random_alphanum $HTcspNonce 32;
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter_types *;
sub_filter **CSP_NONCE** $HTcspNonce;
```

The scripts have `nonce="**CSP_NONCE**"` in the `<script>` tag.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had `zlib.output_compression = On` in php.ini, which was interfering. It's not needed, since I have gzip on in nginx.

Comment: i agreee with this, if you use compression, you should decide to use only one of them, had this in the past, dont forget to accept your answer if possible